# Invariant subspace for Volterra operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

**So, am I stupid or isn't this kind of trivial?**

I'm having this problem:

Let $T$ be the Volterra operator on $L^2([0,1])$ defined by
\begin{equation}
Tf(s) = \int^s_0 \, f(t) \, \text{d}t.
\end{equation}
For $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ set
\begin{equation}
M_{\alpha} = \{f \in L^2([0,1]) : f(t) = 0, 0 \leq t \leq \alpha\}.
\end{equation}

Prove that each $M_{\alpha}$ is an invariant subspace for $T$.

**My solution is this:**

$M_{\alpha}$ is an invariant subspace for $T$ if $f(t) \in M_{\alpha} \Rightarrow Tf(s) \in M_{\alpha}$. So if $f(t) \in M_{\alpha}$, then

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
Tf(s) &= \int^s_0 \, f(t) \, \text{d}t\\
&= \begin{cases}\displaystyle\int^s_0 \, 0 \, \text{d}t &\quad \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq \alpha\\\displaystyle\int^s_0 \, f(t) \, \text{d}t &\quad \text{if } \alpha < t \leq 1\\\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}0 &\quad \text{if } 0 \leq t \leq \alpha\\\displaystyle\int^s_0 \, f(t) \text{d}t &\quad \text{if } \alpha < t \leq 1\\\end{cases}\\
&\in M_{\alpha}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Am I wrong or is it this simple?

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is right if you indeed wishes to prove $M_\alpha$ is invariant subspace. However, it will be nontrivial if you want to prove the converse, namely, every invariant subspace of $T$ is of this form.

References:

D. Sarason, [A remark on the Volterra operator](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X65900351)

W. Donoghue, [The Lattice of invariant subspaces of a
completment continuous quasinilpotent transformation](https://msp.org/pjm/1957/7-2/pjm-v7-n2-p01-s.pdf)